# Load CSS Images under HTTPS

Tags: css, http, https

If I have a CSS file that loads with HTTPS (e.g. https://www.mydomain.com/includes/style.css) that contains

`body { background:url("../images/background.png"); }`

The background pic loads like:  (without HTTPS). Do you know a quick fix around this without putting the full path to the CSS file (needs to be relative)? I'm looking for the easiest fix!

Thanks in advance!

Gabriel

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should give a try to protocol URLs (*[network-path reference](http://michaelshadle.com/2010/07/21/little-known-uri-shorthand-the-network-path-reference)*) to solve your problems when you use HTTP mixed with HTTPS. So your CSS will be in this case something like this :

```
body { background:url("//www.mydomain.com/images/background.png"); }
```